# R equivalent of Excel VLOOKUP

Tags: r, vlookup, dplyr

In order to clean some of my datas, I have tried setting up an Excel VLOOKUP equivalent tu use with a dplyr::mutate() function :

```
vlookup <- 
  function(theString, theMapping) 
  {
    library("magrittr")
    
    which(
        theMapping[1] == theString
      )[1] %>% 
      theMapping[.,2]
  }
```

Testing on a single string works fine :

```
test_mapping <- 
  tibble(
      c("AD", "Andorra")
    , c("AE", "United Arab Emirates")
    , c("AF", "Afghanistan")
    ) %>% 
  t %>% 
  as_tibble

> "AD" %>% vlookup(test_mapping)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  V2     
  <chr>  
1 Andorra
```

However, it doesn't work when applied on a tibble with mutate() :

```
tibble(
  country = c("AE", "AF", "foo")
) %>% 
mutate(
    country_remap = country %>% vlookup(test_mapping)
  )

> tibble(
+   country = c("AE", "AF", "foo")
+ ) %>% 
+ mutate(
+     country_remap = country %>% vlookup(test_mapping)
+   )
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  country country_remap$V2
  <chr>   <chr>           
1 AE      NA              
2 AF      NA              
3 foo     NA
```

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `deframe` to create a named vector and remap more efficiently

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
tibble(
   country = c("AE", "AF", "foo")
 ) %>% mutate(country_remap = deframe(test_mapping)[country])
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  country country_remap       
#  <chr>   <chr>               
#1 AE      United Arab Emirates
#2 AF      Afghanistan         
#3 foo     <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `vlookup` function is not vectorized meaning it works for one value at a time. If you add `rowwise` in your pipe it works as expected.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tibble(country = c("AE", "AF", "foo")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(country_remap = country %>% vlookup(test_mapping))

# country country_remap$V2    
#  <chr>   <chr>               
#1 AE      United Arab Emirates
#2 AF      Afghanistan         
#3 foo     NA
```

However, this is not efficient. You should instead join the dataframes in R.

```
tibble(country = c("AE", "AF", "foo")) %>%
  left_join(test_mapping, by = c('country' = 'V1'))
```